# Command 'react-native log-android' stuck at 'Starting Logkitty'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, adb

I'm trying to run a React Native project and after trying to start it, it produces an error which I'm trying to debug, but while trying to debug that error the command gets stuck.

I've tried using 'react-native log-android' but for some reason it gets stuck at 'Starting logkitty'

[image: This is the error that's occuring]

Comment: This tool is completely broken, even though it's an essential part of React-Native development. Does anyone maintain that project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and the following solution worked for me.

First make sure you have an adb device connected to your system by running the command `adb devices` from you terminal and check if any devices get listed under the line: `List of devices attached`.

Now after running the command `react-native log-android`, 'Reload' code on your device and the logkitty should start logging fine.

Comment: Why would listing the devices change anything? How is this a solution?

Comment: Listing of devices is done just to make sure that is there any adb device connected to get logs from.The main thing I suggested was doing a "Reload". Actually the logkitty stays in waiting state unless it gets something to log from the device. So the OP might have confused that waiting state as being 'stuck'. That's why I advised to do a reload of the app as it generates logs to the console. Basically any activity that generates logs (reload / hot-reload / restarting the app / console.log etc.) makes the logkitty come out from that "waiting" (_stuck_) state.

Comment: This worked for me. All I wanted to do is to reload by double tapping `R`.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal may keep showing "info Starting logkitty" after `npx react-native log-android` command.
The log data may appear if present, after navigating through the screens of the project in an android device or emulator which is running the project after `npx react-native run-android` command.